# Disable "Server Violation: Punkbuster Disabled" message while playing COD 4 with BOTS

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare, punkbuster

Ok so while playing COD 4 Multiplayer on a LAN wit BOTS (PEZbots) i keep getting this annoying message on the game while playing which says "Server Violation: Punkbuster Disabled". I dont wanna play with the Punkbuster enabled, so is there any simple way of getting rid of this message from my game screen while playing???? Maybe by using the console or something????

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, although I really don't know what PEZbots is, it might be a mod, therefore that can cause Punkbuster to disable.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you may have left punkbuster enabled when you started the server. You need to make sure Punkbuster is disabled when you start your offline game. You can see in this guide how to setup your server: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1577358970#2810765